# How do I re-size an image that's being display via a link in a JSON?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

This is what my code currently looks like.

```
<div id= "logos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][1]["visitorTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"] %></div>
```

It's getting the logo for me, but I need to be able to re-size the logo to a more appropriate size. I've tried the typical CSS code like "max-width", etc, but all that does is shrink the area where the window where logo squeezes into (so I can scroll around in this small window and see the image still at it's usual size), it doesn't actually shrink the logo itself.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please show use the scss you tried to apply and, if possible, the image itself (might be a lot of fun if it is badly formatted SVG)

Comment: There are *many* ways to do this. You can resize the image on the server side with libraries like imagemagic. You can use the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)  css attribute or the [sizes attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-sizes).

Comment: `@schedule["data"][1]["visitorTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"]` is also extremely ugly. There is no way your view should be traversing an entire data structure multiple levels deep and is just a bug waiting to happen. Normalize data from other sources to your application and pass that your view.

Comment: @max so then where should I be transversing the data structure at? in my controller? I've only started working with Rails and API's this week but I recognized early on when I was making it actually work that it's pretty complex in my view but I haven't found any instruction on how to simplify things.

Comment: It depends entirely on where this is coming from. If its from an API call it should be handled in a seperate class (either a client class or a service object). There is no one answer to that question and not everything in Rails should be shoehorned into models, views or controllers even through thats the components that are in focus when learning Rails.

Comment: @max It is an API call. I made another thread where I posted all of my code where hopefully I can learn how to clean it up and where to put those calls.